# symfony 2.x / doctrine 2.4 app/console requires database

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my CI environment I'm dropping the DB and recreating it on every new build. On older  projects this works fine. On a newer project this suddenly starts failing.

When running

```
php app/console doctrine:database:drop --env=test --force
```

Everything goes fine. But after that, all console commands, like

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

start giving the error

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database '(my database)'
```

This is the error I get when trying to create the new database with doctrine, so I suspect it has more to do with the bootstrapping Symfony does when running console.

I've tested the problem by downgrading Symfony from 2.5 to 2.3, forcing Symfony and Doctrine to same versions as in another project where the app/console doesn't break - to no result. I' currently tracing the common ground on running different commands, and suspect bootstrap.php might be able to provide some clues as to where it might break.

Comment: what if you create a database manualy?

Comment: Works ok manually. It seems to be related to Symfony bootstrapping when running commands.

Comment: try to `php app/console doctrine:database:create` before import entities

Comment: @Trone After having dropped the database, all the console commands break. This is related to how doctrine bootstraps itself in symfony bootstrap procedure - it tries to look for the DB, doesn't find it and breaks. This seems to be a bug introduced in newer doctrine version.

Comment: @Markus I had to simply create the table manually and rest of the commands worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ php app/console doctrine:database:drop --force
$ php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

There's no way to configure these defaults inside Doctrine, as it tries to be as agnostic as possible in terms of environment configuration. One way to solve this problem is to configure server-level defaults.

Setting UTF8 defaults for MySQL is as simple as adding a few lines to your configuration file (typically my.cnf):

[mysqld]

```
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
character-set-server = utf8
```

source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Comment: The thing is, with a certain symfony/doctrine version combination this doesn't work.